# Why create a struct of function pointers inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers, assignment-operator, skia

I was digging around in the Vulkan backend for the Skia graphics API, found [here](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/main/src/gpu/vk/VulkanInterface.h), and I don't understand a piece of code.

Here's the smallest code example:

```
struct VulkanInterface : public SkRefCnt {

public:
    VulkanInterface(VulkanGetProc getProc,
                    VkInstance instance,
                    VkDevice device,
                    uint32_t instanceVersion,
                    uint32_t physicalDeviceVersion,
                    const VulkanExtensions*);

    /**
     * The function pointers are in a struct so that we can have a compiler generated assignment
     * operator.
     */
    struct Functions {
        VkPtr<PFN_vkCreateInstance> fCreateInstance;
        VkPtr<PFN_vkDestroyInstance> fDestroyInstance;

        // a ton more functions here
    } fFunctions;
};
```

Why would you create a struct of function pointers in a class?

Why this extra layer of abstraction where you have to add `fFunctions->` everywhere?

I know there's a comment with an explanation and I know what those words mean, but I don't understand the comment as a whole. I just need it broken down a little more. Thanks.

Comment: They want use `fFunctions = functions;` or `fFunctions = {create, destroy};` somewhere.

Comment: You do this if you want to implement your own version of runtime polymorphism. It allows you to represent the entirety of an instance's behavior as a single value.

Comment: This is hand made variant of inheritance and virtual functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regular polymorphic inheritance

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo();
    // ...
};

struct D1 : Base
{
    void foo() override;
    // ...
};

struct D2 : Base
{
    void foo() override;
    // ...
};
```

You cannot assign to base class without slicing:

```
D1 d1;
Base b = d1;
b.foo(); // call Base::Foo
```

or treat object with value semantic:

```
D1 d1;
D2 d2;
d2 = d1; // Illegal
```

you have to use (smart) pointer instead.

In addition, you cannot mix (at runtime) from different virtual functions

```
Base base;
base.foo = &D2::foo; // imaginary syntax, Illegal
base.bar = &D1::bar; // imaginary syntax, Illegal
```

Having those function pointers inside the class allow the above (at the price of bigger object).

```
struct VulkanInterface
{
    void (*foo) ();
    void (*bar) (VulkanInterface& self);
    // ...
};

VulkanInterface makeVulkanInterface1() { return {my_foo, my_bar}; }
VulkanInterface makeVulkanInterface2() { return {my_foo2, my_bar2}; }
```

```
VulkanInterface v1 = makeVulkanInterface1();
VulkanInterface v2 = makeVulkanInterface2();
VulkanInterface v = v1;
v = v2;
v.foo = v1.foo;
v.bar(v);
```